# Which Version of Ubuntu to Install on old 2008 intel atom netbook (acer)

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, 14.10

i was wondering what version of ubuntu should i install on my old netbook? should it be 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS, or 14.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looking for full performance with up to date, you should select xubuntu.

ubuntu 14.04 would work fine but there might be some lags if you're using hdd as well. for example i have an acer aspire 5710g with coreduo cpu and hd2300 gpu from 2007(i think) however it was just a lag machine with hdd so i got a ssd for $70 and installed 12.04 LTS in that (i love unity gui)

and i assume you're using aspire one, xubuntu 14.04 or ubuntu 12.04 LTS would be best for you. Intel Atom is an slow cpu.